# How to get previous url and navigate him after clicking back button?

Tags: angular

I'm using this in constructor in component:

```
  this.router.events
    .filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .pairwise().subscribe((e) => {
        this.previousUrl = e[0].url;
    });
```

Now i have this at same component:

```
  returnToPreviousPage(){
        console.log(this.previousUrl);
        // this.router.navigate([this.previousUrl]);
    }
```

But i always get undefined. Any suggestion how can i use that previous url and when user hit return button to navigate him to

```
 this.previousUrl
```

Comment: i didnt downvote him, someone else was

Answer (score 0):

You can go to previous page by doing that:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component ({
    // ...
})

export class MyComponent {

    constructor(private location: Location) { }

    goBack(): void {
        this.location.back();
    }  
}
```

Comment: i cannot use this.location.back() because i need to send some params on back button